# Getting more details from NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsfilemanager

Is there a way to get more details (size,date created,etc) about a specific item when using `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` or a similar method?

I really need to be able to distinguish between files and folders in a directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to look at the following method from NSFileManager:

```
- (NSDictionary *)attributesOfItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

The dictionary of attributes returned contains many keys, but the NSFileType key will help you determine whether the path points to an NSFileTypeDirectory (directory) or a NSFileTypeRegular (regular file). The following keys may also be of interest:

```
NSFileSize
NSFileCreationDate
NSFileModificationDate
```

Answer (score 0):

`CFURLURLEnumerator` will do this and prefetch properties you specify. if performance/time is a concern, then you should favor a lower level approach such as this. higher level apis may fetch more properties from the filesystem than you are interested in - which can add a lot of time to your crawl.